# C++ Get variable value by concatenated name of the variable

Tags: c++, variables, reference, concatenation

I don't know if this is possible but I'll try to explain:

I've got the following variables:

```
const char * VAR1 = "var1";
const char * VAR2 = "var2";

const char * VAR1_A = "etc1";
const char * VAR2_A = "etc2";
```

And then I declare a `std:vector` and put the variables in:

```
vector <const char *> v1;
v1.push_back(VAR1);
v1.push_back(VAR2);
```

Then I iterate over the vector to find a match this way:

```
const char * param = "var1"; //Example parameter

for(int x=0; x<v1.size(); x++){

   //Found a match in the vector
   if(param == v1[x]){

      //HERE is the point. I need to get the value of variable "[v1[x](NAME)]_A"
      //Something like:
      const char * varname = getVarName(v1[x]) + "_A"; //This would contain VAR1_A
      const char * varvalue = getVarValueByVarName(varname); //This would contain "etc1";
      break;
   }

}
```

Is this a good reasoning for my problem or there's an existent method for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use [`std::map<std::string, std::string>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/).

That way you can do something like this:

```
map<string, string> myMap;
myMap["var1"] = "var1_value";
myMap["var2"] = "var2_value"; 
//say now you get input into a variable named 'str' for what variable the user wants to print
cout << myMap[str] << endl;
```

The operator `[]` will add to the map if the key (in this case, a string) does not exist and will change the value if it does.